# VB to download torrent, deflate gzipped section selectively

Tags: encoding, download, gzip, httprequest, utorrent

Apologies if this is a basic question, i'm a very casual programmer.

I'm writing a program which will search for torrents, grab them based on certain criteria (one being that they are indicated as freeware, you'll be pleased to hear) and then throw them over  to utorrent. I'm getting stuck downloading the .torrent file, because, I believe, of the encoding.

I've worked out thus far that the bulk of the top of the file can be gzip deflated on the fly using HTTPrequest - but it seems that half-way through the file, something changes - and looking in a hex editor at a .torrent i've grabbed from a site directly versus the one I download here, everything is identical up to a point, then all is totally different.

If i'm being vague i'm afraid it's because i'm making this all up as I go along! Is it likely that the encoding / compression in a torrent file would change part way through, and how could I catch this in VB to avoid corrupting the latter half?

Thanks very much in advance,
Dan

Comment: Put more elegantly; > Is it likely that the encoding/compression will change part-way through a download using HTTPrequest, and IF SO, > How should I go about detecting and handling this? Thanks!

Comment: once you grab them,  use something like a command line version of maketorrent. it will open and add them auto to utorrent.  Just have your app send the command line to it run it